# Endpoint Configuration type EDGE is not supported in this region

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to launch a AWS API Gateway via CloudFormation (YAML + Swagger).

When trying to launch the stack via the console I keep getting;

"Endpoint Configuration type EDGE is not supported in this region: us-gov-west-1"

I've specified the Endpoint Configuration as "REGIONAL", but it doesn't seem to be taking.

This API Gateway has been created successfully via the console, so I'd assume it should work using a CloudFormation.

At this point I'm guessing that by default it's going with EDGE and that this may not even be supported in the gov region.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  rTestAPI:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: Test API
      Description: A test API
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
      Body:
        swagger: '2.0'
        info:
          version: '2019-01-11T16:05:08Z'
          title: test-api
        # host: 9lazpn2fob.execute-api.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
        basePath: /default
        schemes:
          - https
        paths:
          /test:
            post:
              consumes:
                - application/json
                - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
              produces:
                - application/json
                - text/html
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: 200 response
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/Empty'
                  headers:
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      type: string
                    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
                      type: string
                    Content-Type:
                      type: string
                '400':
                  description: 400 response
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
                  headers:
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      type: string
                    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
                      type: string
                    Content-Type:
                      type: string
            options:
              consumes:
                - application/json
              produces:
                - application/json
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: 200 response
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/surveydata'
                  headers:
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      type: string
                    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                      type: string
                    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
                      type: string
        definitions:
          Empty:
            type: object
            title: Empty Schema
          Error:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string
            title: Error Schema
          surveydata:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
            title: Survey Data Schema
```

My expected result is that the CloudFormation creates the API Gateway with a REGIONAL endpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When importing a `Body` using `Swagger`, CFN ignores the `EndpointConfiguration` field.  To work around this, try adding the `endpointConfigurationTypes` to the `Parameters` as per the below example:

```
 ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        endpointConfigurationTypes: REGIONAL
        ignore: documentation
      BodyS3Location:
        Bucket: BATS::SAM::CodeS3Bucket
        Key:xxxxxx
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
        - REGIONAL
```

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: It works for me. I just add those in my xml file for create stack.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem in China and for one stack which I updated to include a Swagger body it worked, for another stack which I created it didn't work.

So the only workaround that I was able to use is to deploy the stack and the API Gateway without a Swagger Body, and then include the Swagger Body and update the stack. What I did was create this empty stack:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "The AWS CloudFormation template for this Serverless application",
    "Resources": {
        "ApiGatewayRestApi": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "my-api-name",
                "EndpointConfiguration": {
                    "Types": [ "REGIONAL" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which was created successfully. Note that you must use the same logical id in order to update it (in my case it's "ApiGatewayRestApi"). After that, I took the actual template with the Swagger and updated it.

Hope this helps!